# momentjs is not calculating the week number correctly

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, moment-timezone

I’m trying to calculate the week number from the epoch time that I’m receiving from the backend. So the value that I receive from the backend is this `1571097600000(15th October 2019)`. Now when I change this epoch date to start of the week  using this code

```
moment(1571097600000).startOf("week").unix()*1000
```

what I get is this `1570906800000(13th October 2019)`. But when I format this date the week number is incorrect. This is how I’m formatting

```
moment.(1570906800000).format("W, YYYY")
```

The value that I get is `41` but actually the week number is `42`. Any idea what is going on over here

Here is the code that I'm using

```
console.log(moment(1571097600000).startOf("week").unix()*1000)
console.log(moment(1571097600000).startOf("week").format("W, YYYY"))
```

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that your system settings are for the start of week on Sunday, but ISO weeks start on Monday.

Your initial time value is for  Tue 15 Oct 2019, however when you do *startOfWeek*, the date is set to Sun 13 Oct 2019, which is the previous ISO week. Moment.js claims to use "locale aware" start of week, however I don't know how robust that is. I'd suggest always using ISO weeks.

If you want to use ISO weeks, use [*startOf('isoWeek')*](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/).

```js
let mLocal = moment(1571097600000);
let mISO = mLocal.clone();
let f = 'ddd DD MMM YYYY';
console.log('Start date : ' + mLocal.format(f));

// "locale aware" start of week
mLocal.startOf("week");
// ISO start of week
mISO.startOf("isoWeek");


console.log('Local start: ' + mLocal.format(f));
console.log('ISO week   : ' + mLocal.format("W, YYYY"))
console.log('ISO start  : ' + mISO.format(f));
console.log('ISO week   : ' + mISO.format("W, YYYY"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, this is a much better answer so I deleted mine.